# How do I create a search form with filters?

Tags: 7, forms, search

I have to create a searching form for a custom post type and I need it to have one search box and a couple of different (optional) search options in the form of select lists. I know I could have only the search text field and then expose the filters in the results page, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Is this possible? What modules/requirements would I need for something like this?

Comment: Have you tried the Views module?

Comment: Yes, but how do I manage the search form to display the filters before I actually search? Eg: Front page only has a search field and two filters (say color and price), instead of front page only has a search field and search results page has exposed filters with color and price... How would I do the first version?

Comment: I have posted a similar question (sorry for the duplicate - been searching for hours): [http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45268/how-do-i-build-a-search-form-with-filter-options-checkboxes](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45268/how-do-i-build-a-search-form-with-filter-options-checkboxes) Have you found an answer?